# Issues with Runtime.exec Process.getInputStream and Process.waitFor()

Tags: java, multiprocessing

I have written a code to check whether HSQL, JBoss, Radius (AAA sever) and MySQL is running or not.The code is written in an inifinte while loop to continuously monitor.Now I tested that if this service (let's say hsql) is running then `/bin/bash -c ps -ef | grep 'hsql' | wc -l` will return 3 when this is passed as an argument in `Runtime.exec()` method.  Now I have come to know that the inputstream or errstream of the forked process must not be overflowed.  Otherwise it'll cause deadlock.

Keeping that in mind I have written this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.util.Date;

public class MonitorHsqlJBossRadius {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String hsqlCmd[] = {"/bin/bash","-c","ps -ef | grep 'hsql' | wc -l "};  
        String jbossCommand[] = {"/bin/sh","-c","ps -ef | grep 'jboss' | wc -l"};  
        String radiusCommand[] = {"/bin/sh","-c","ps -ef | grep 'radius' | wc -l"};  
        String mySqlCommand[] = {"/bin/sh","-c","/etc/init.d/mysqld status"};  
        String line = null;  
        String mobNo = "(obscured)";  
        Process process = null;  
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();  
        BufferedReader reader = null;  
        SendSMS sender = new SendSMS();  
        boolean sendMsgHsql = false;  
        boolean sendMsgJBoss = false;  
        boolean sendMsgRadius = false;  
        int itr = 1;  
        while(true)  
        {  
            try
            {  
                process = runtime.exec(hsqlCmd);  
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)  
                {  
                    if (!line.equals("3"))  
                        sendMsgHsql = true;  
                }  

                process.waitFor();  
                if (sendMsgHsql)  
                {  
                    //sender.sendSMS("HSQL is not running "+(new Date().toString()), mobNo,1,itr);  
                    System.out.println("HSQL is not running "+itr);  
                }  
                else  
                    System.out.println("HSQL is running "+itr);  

                sendMsgHsql = false;  

                process = runtime.exec(jbossCommand);  
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)  
                {  
                    if (!line.equals("3"))  
                       sendMsgJBoss = true;  
                }  

                process.waitFor();  
                if (sendMsgJBoss)  
                {  
                    //sender.sendSMS("JBoss is not running "+(new Date().toString()), mobNo,2,itr);  
                    System.out.println("JBoss is not running "+itr);  
                }  
                else  
                    System.out.println("JBoss is running "+itr);  

                sendMsgJBoss = false;  

                process = runtime.exec(radiusCommand);  
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)  
                {  
                    if(!line.equals("3"))  
                        sendMsgRadius = true;  
                }  

                process.waitFor();  
                if (sendMsgRadius)  
                {  
                    //sender.sendSMS("Radius is not running "+(new Date().toString()), mobNo,3,itr);  
                    System.out.println("Radius is not running "+itr);  
                }  
                else  
                    System.out.println("Radius is running "+itr);  

                sendMsgRadius = false;  
            }   


            catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }   
            catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            try  
            {  
                System.out.println("\n--------- "+itr+" ------------\n");  
                itr++;  
                Thread.sleep(1000*5);  
            }  
            catch (InterruptedException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm expecting is as follows

```
HSQL is running/not running 1
JBoss is running/not running 1
MySQL is running/not running 1
-------------------1----------------

HSQL is running/not running 2
JBoss is running/not running 2
MySQL is running/not running 2
-------------------2----------------
```

and so on...

Howevere I'm not getting output like that.  Sometimes HSQL's status message is not printed or sometimes JBoss status message is not printed.  Even sometimes I get output like

```
------------------1----------------------
```

after this status messages are printed.  All I'm trying to say is that seems to be some race condition or some synchronization problem.

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted code posted....

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way. You can see how to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

Trying to determine whether a process is running by parsing the output of ps is usually not a good idea.  The typical error is that `grep processname` matches (atleast) two processes: both processname and the grep-process itself.

The usual way of doing this is:

- when starting the process, write the pid to a file
- when checking the process, read the pid from file and see if it exists by sending it a signal

An even more robust and elegant way of doing it, is to let the process open a socket and checking if this is available, but in this case you wouldn't want to add code for this in your servers.  However, the processes you want to check already listen to TCP-ports.  I would write code that tried to connect to this port (typically port 80 for jboss, 3306 for mysql, 9001 for hsql)  Radius is a bit more tricky as it uses UDP.  You could try to perform an authentication, or you could look for specific characteristics with your particular radius-server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your code is hanging due to a race condition or synchronization at all.  I don't have access to your server, so I can't run your code to be sure, but instead I suspect that the processes you are running are blocking because they are writing to their standard error and you are not reading from it.

It is possible to read from the standard error stream of a Process created by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but reading from this stream has to be done in a separate thread.  Instead, I would recommend using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  In my opinion, the most significant benefit of a ProcessBuilder is that it can redirect the standard error of the process into the same stream as the standard output.  This means you only have one stream to read from and there is no need for a separate thread.

I'll also note that you are opening various `BufferedReader`s but not closing them.  I would recommend that you close them when you have finished with them.

Finally, I would recommend that you don't repeat virtually the same code three times.  It should be possible to write a method that takes the command line to run as a `String` array parameter, runs the command line using a ProcessBuilder and returns whether a line `3` was  among the output from that command.